# matplotlib plotting legend corresponding to size and color of points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to create a legend for a scatter plot similar to [scatter_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) The legend should show the color and size of the the largest and smallest points. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (10 * np.random.rand(N) + 3)**2

plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, edgecolors='face')

b_idx = area.argmax()
s_idx = area.argmin()

plt.scatter(x[b_idx], y[b_idx], s=area[b_idx], c=colors[b_idx],label='big')
plt.scatter(x[s_idx], y[s_idx], s=area[s_idx], c=colors[s_idx], label='small')

plt.legend(title = 'Size and Color')
plt.show()
```

my_plot

[image]

This does not put the correct colors into the legend.  Also my approach double plots points. This creates a small crescent behind the original point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the scatter points is determined from the input array `colors` by mapping the input values to a colormap. (In the case here, the colormap is the default colormap, implicitely set in the scatter call.)
However, the color used in the legend is the standard color from the colorcycle.

As @DavidG pointed out in his solution, one way to overcome this is to use an array of rgb colors instead of an array of values to specify the colors of the points. While this solves the issue of coloring the legend entries, it has 2 major drawbacks: (a) You loose the ability to use a colormap and (b) In a real world case, the data to show as colors are not colors themselves, but some scalar quantity to be visualized using color.

It is therefore highly beneficial to stick to the input `colors` array and modify the code afterwards to show the respective minimally and maximally sized points in color in the legend. To this end, one would need to find out which color they have and provide this to the proxy artists used to create the legend. 
This can be done using the `to_rgba` method from the the scatter plot itself (which is a `ScalarMappable` object).

Finally in order not to have the points drawn twice in the plot, one can simply provide empty coordinate arrays to the proxy scatters.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(20)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (10 * np.random.rand(N) + 3)**2

sc = plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, edgecolors='face')

b_idx = area.argmax()
s_idx = area.argmin()

plt.scatter([], [], s=area[b_idx], c=sc.to_rgba(colors[b_idx]),label='big')
plt.scatter([], [], s=area[s_idx], c=sc.to_rgba(colors[s_idx]),label='small')

plt.legend(title = 'Size and Color')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with your array `colors`. It needs to be a 3xN array representing N RGB colours. Therefore, to fix the code that you have provided, use the following line:

```
colors = np.random.rand(N,3)
```

Then, keeping the rest of the code unchanged the following graph is produced:

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that in the real world, you never want to plot colors as colors, but values mapped to colors. So changing the input array is most definetely never an option.