# adding legend to scatterplot in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, classification

I have the following code for visualizing decision boundary for a binary classification problem:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn import neighbors, datasets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_C2, y_C2,
                                                   random_state=0)
n_neighbors = [1, 3, 11]
weights = 'uniform'
h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# Create color maps (http://htmlcolorcodes.com/)
cmap_light = ListedColormap(['#F9F999', '#F3F3F3'])
cmap_bold = ListedColormap(['#FFFF00', '#000000'])
# For example, FF AA AA = RGB(255, 170, 170) 

for n in n_neighbors:
    # we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
    clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n, weights=weights)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # ----------------------------- Mesh color i.e. background color begins ------------------------
    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    x_min, x_max = X_train[:, 0].min() - 1, X_train[:, 0].max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = X_train[:, 1].min() - 1, X_train[:, 1].max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                         np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    plt.figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
    plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=cmap_light)
    # ------------------------------ Mesh color i.e. background color ends -------------------------

    # Plot also the training points
    # plt.figure(figsize=(10,4), dpi=80)
    plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cmap_bold, s=40, label = "class 0") # scatter plot of height vs width
    plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train, cmap=cmap_bold, s=40, label = "class 1") # scatter plot of height vs width
    plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    plt.title("2-Class classification (k = %i, weights = '%s')" % (n, weights))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

The best I could do is:
[image]
But the legend doesn't correspond to the actual class of the points. The X_train has 2 columns one for each feature. The y_train contains the label for this data namely 0's and 1's. How to obtain a legend that has the same color as the points?

Comment: Possibly relevant as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706976/matplotlib-plotting-legend-corresponding-to-size-and-color-of-points

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - Can you please say which question is my question duplicate of?

Comment: Both. And there are also others. If they don't help you, you need to explain in detail why the solutions provided don't help you here and provide a [mcve] of the issue (which is completely independent of things like a `KNeighborsClassifier`).